# Serializing a class which contains a std::string

Tags: c++, serialization, binaryfiles

I'm not a c++ expert but I've serialized things a couple of times in the past. Unfortunately this time I'm trying to serialize a class which contains an `std::string`, which I understand is pretty much like serializing a pointer.

I can write out the class to a file and read it back in again. All `int` fields are fine, but the `std::string` field gives an "address out of bounds" error, presumably because it points to data which is no longer there.

Is there a standard workaround for this? I don't want to go back to `char` arrays, but at least I know they work in this situation. I can provide code if necessary, but I'm hoping I've explained my problem well.

I'm serializing by casting the class to a `char*` and writing it to a file with `std::fstream`. Reading of course is just the reverse.

Comment: IMO, you'll have to dump string data manually. Prepare a plain structure which has a char buffer and the string length and serialize it instead of original object.

Comment: It ssems to be the only real issue is how you delimit the string, but you would face that issue with a char array as well. I'm not getting where you are having trouble, seems very easy to serialise a string to me. Probably you better post some code.

Comment: The java has standard serialization (in standard library). C++ have no such functionality nor in the language nor in the STL library. There is an external libs to do such, e.g. boost can do this. Other variant is using of google's protocol buffers.

Comment: Nitpicking: you're serializing an _object_.

Comment: An intermediate structure does make sense to me. It does beg the question why I'm bothering with these strings in the first place, it seems to be a false economy in the long run.

Comment: I will edit the original post with some code shortly. A little further explanation though. When the object is written, the ints are written as numbers, but the string is written as a pointer address instead of characters. Hence unless memory remains unchanged, the string is lost on reading.

Comment: I'm guessing you are doing this `out << &str;`, that's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: If you're on Linux, another good method is to construct an array of IOVs and give it to `writev` function(http://linux.die.net/man/2/writev) to write everything in one shot.

Comment: @iwas: "False economy"?  You mean apart from the automatic memory management, integration with streams, etc., etc.?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I'm serializing by casting the class to a char* and writing it to a
>   file with fstream. Reading of course is just the reverse.

Unfortunately, this only works as long as there are no pointers involved.  You might want to give your classes `void MyClass::serialize(std::ostream)` and `void MyClass::deserialize(std::ifstream)`, and call those.  For this case, you'd want

```
std::ostream& MyClass::serialize(std::ostream &out) const {
    out << height;
    out << ',' //number seperator
    out << width;
    out << ',' //number seperator
    out << name.size(); //serialize size of string
    out << ',' //number seperator
    out << name; //serialize characters of string
    return out;
}
std::istream& MyClass::deserialize(std::istream &in) {
    if (in) {
        int len=0;
        char comma;
        in >> height;
        in >> comma; //read in the seperator
        in >> width;
        in >> comma; //read in the seperator
        in >> len;  //deserialize size of string
        in >> comma; //read in the seperator
        if (in && len) {
            std::vector<char> tmp(len);
            in.read(tmp.data() , len); //deserialize characters of string
            name.assign(tmp.data(), len);
        }
    }
    return in;
}
```

You may also want to overload the stream operators for easier use.

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyClass &obj)
{obj.serialize(out); return out;}
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream& in, MyClass &obj)
{obj.deserialize(in); return in;}
```

Comment: Looks interesting and not too disruptive to the existing code/workflow. I'll have a play. thanks

Comment: (1) Your streams need to be passed by reference, istream and ostream copy constructors are disabled. (2) width and height and the size of the string will be concatenated together on output, so reading them back in will result in a single number.

Comment: `in.read(&name[0], len);` that is surely wrong. You cannot treat a string like a vector. And even as a vector it would fail if len == 0.

Comment: @john: agreed. An intermediate `char *nameValue = new char[len + 1];` seems to be required.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: whoops, I forgot to make them by reference.  My bad.

Comment: @John and Rudy: nope.  std::string (non-const) operator[] returns a char&, so the address of that is a char* into the string.  Since I've resized to the exact length, this is all defined behavior, and works.  (Although it would have failed if len was zero)

Comment: Writing using `c_str()` is going to create problems if the strings has embedded NUL chars (\0) because less characters will be written. You should either writing the correct number of characters looping over the string or write `strlen(c_str())` instead of `size` if you want to drop characters after the first NUL. Writing `size` and `c_str` will make you reading corrupted data if a NUL is stored in a string.

Comment: @John and Rudy: I stand corrected, std::string is not guaranteed to be contiguous.  Temporary is required.

Comment: Wish I could reset the votes and uncheck accepted answer, this code has changed quite a bit since it was accepted :(

Comment: `auto_ptr` should not be used for arrays.  It it only calls `delete`, not `delete[]`.  Try a `vector<char>`, you can read directly into it from a file using `&v[0]`.

Answer (score 10):

Simply writing the binary contents of an object into a file is not only unportable but, as you've recognized, doesn't work for pointer data. You basically have two options: either you write a real serialization library, which handles std::strings properly by e.g. using [c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) to output the actual string to the file, or you use the excellent [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library. If at all possible, I'd recommend the latter, you can then serialize with a simple code like this:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

class A {
    private:
        std::string s;
    public:
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & s;
        }
};
```

Here, the function `serialize` works for serializing and deserializing the data, depending on how you call it. See the documentation for more information.

Comment: Excellent idea.  However it looks as if you show an example of the 'latter' - use boost, while you advise the 'former'...

Comment: I haven't dug in to boost before but I'll check it out next. thanks

Answer (score 3):

The easiest serialization method for strings or other blobs with variable size is to serialize first the size as you serialize integers, then just copy the content to the output stream.

When reading you first read the size, then allocate the string and then fill it by reading the correct number of bytes from the stream.

An alternative is to use a delimiter and escaping, but requires more code and is slower both on serialization and deserialization (however the result can be kept human readable).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a more complicated method of serialization than casting a class to a `char*` and writing it to a file if your class contains any exogenous data (`string` does). And you're correct about why you're getting a segmentation fault.

I would make a member function that would take an `fstream` and read in the data from it as well as an inverse function which would take an `fstream` and write it's contents to it to be restored later, like this:

```
class MyClass {
pubic:
    MyClass() : str() { }

    void serialize(ostream& out) {
        out << str;
    }

    void restore(istream& in) {
        in >> str;
    }

    string& data() const { return str; }

private:
    string str;
};

MyClass c;
c.serialize(output);

// later
c.restore(input);
```

You can also define `operator<<` and `operator>>` to work with `istream` and `ostream` to serialize and restore your class as well if you want that syntactic sugar.

Comment: Would the write/read actions act differently if used as member functions? I'm not really understanding how that would write the actual characters instead of the pointer address.

Comment: @iwasinnamuknow: No write and read actions don't act differently when used as member function, what gives you that idea?

Comment: @iwasinnamuknow It's using `operator<<` and `>>` of `(i|o)stream` on a `string` which is defined to write the contents of the string to file. You'd obviously have more data members than one string, so you'd just write them all to the output file and then read them in from the input file in the same order.

Comment: @john it was just a quick example.

Comment: This would stop reading at the first space in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just something along the lines of:

```
std::ofstream ofs;
...

ofs << my_str;
```

and then:

```
std::ifstream ifs;
...

ifs >> my_str;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that assume that the string is separate from anything else? I'm trying to have the entire class and its contents written/read in one go.

Comment: If that's interspersed with other data, or if the string has spaces in it, the input will not be accurate.

Comment: Would that work with a string that contains spaces and/or newlines?

Comment: @iwas: You cannot simply reinterpret a class as a `char *`.  In general, serialization of objects requires (semi-)manually serializing each member variable in turn.  I'm not quite sure what sort of solution you're looking for!

Comment: @John: Good point, no it wouldn't.  But then it wouldn't work with raw `char *`, either.

Comment: @Oli: This is the point surely, the OP is claiming that serialising a std::string is somehow harder than serialising a char array. That's the bit I don't get and until he explains himself I don't think we're going to get very far.

Comment: @oli I'm following one of the multitude of guides that simply suggest casting the class and writing it out. This does work except where a pointer is concerned. And the string is acting like a pointer. A static length char array works fine as well in my quick test. I'm trimming up some code now.

Comment: @iwas: No, there are many more cases where that won't work.  It can only possibly work for [PODs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) (plain-old data structures).

Comment: @Oli I understand, I'm checking out the boost serialization now in addition to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*!
 * reads binary data into the string.
 * @status : OK.
*/

class UReadBinaryString
{
    static std::string read(std::istream &is, uint32_t size)
    {
        std::string returnStr;
        if(size > 0)
        {
            CWrapPtr<char> buff(new char[size]);       // custom smart pointer
            is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff.m_obj), size);
            returnStr.assign(buff.m_obj, size);
        }

        return returnStr;
    }
};

class objHeader
{
public:
    std::string m_ID;

    // serialize
    std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os)
    {
        uint32_t size = (m_ID.length());
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(uint32_t));
        os.write(m_ID.c_str(), size);

        return os;
    }
    // de-serialize
    std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &is)
    {
        uint32_t size;
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(uint32_t));
        m_ID = UReadBinaryString::read(is, size);

        return is;
     }
};
```

Comment: @RocketR. Did i write union. Well fixed. You know its was quick past of code portions from some old my project files..