# C++ reading/writing objects with binary files

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have gone through hours of time trying to fix the issue of binary file manipulation.

The task is to read and write **BookStoreBook objects** to/from a binary file

The **BookStoreBook class** contains the following member variables:

```
string isbn;
string title;
Author author;
string publisher;
Date dateAdded;
int quantityOnHand;
double wholesaleCost;
double retailPrice;
```

The code for **reading books** is as shown:

```
fstream file("inventory.txt", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);    
vector<BookStoreBook> books:
BookStoreBook *book = (BookStoreBook *)new char[sizeof(BookStoreBook)];
file.read((char*)book, sizeof(BookStoreBook));
while (!file.eof())
{
     books.push_back(*book);
     file.read((char*)book, sizeof(BookStoreBook));
}
```

The code for **writing books** is as shown:

```
vector<BookStoreBook> writeBooks = library.getBooks(); //library contains books
file.close();
file.open("inventory.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);

for(int i = 0; i < writeBooks.size(); i++)
{
     BookStoreBook *book = (BookStoreBook *)new char[sizeof(BookStoreBook)];
     book = &writeBooks[i];
     file.write((char*)book, sizeof(BookStoreBook));
     file.clear();
}
file.clear();
file.close();
```

I don't want to convert any string to a c_str(), as this is prohibited in the assignment requirements.

Some notes:

> Right when I run the program, the program tries to read books from the file, and
>   that is when we get a Windows error window, later when i debug, i get the following message:
>       Unhandled exception at 0x56b3caa4 (msvcr100d.dll) in FinalProject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0084ef10
>
> The funny thing is, sometimes the program runs perfectly fine, and
>   sometimes it crashes when it first reads the books from the file.
>
> However, whenever the program has successfully read some contents, and
>   I dont modify the books, and then reopen the program, the program keeps
>   running perfectly.

Nothing seems to work. Please help!

Comment: You want to run your program in a debugger.

Comment: When your approach serializes pointers, you will serialize the pointer itself, but not what is pointed to.  That's what's happening here, if `string` means `std::string`.

Comment: actually, i got that error message through the visual studio debuger

Comment: what do the classes for Author and Date look like?

Comment: author only contains two strings(first, last), date contains three int's(day, month, year)

Comment: Check that your BookStoreBook class is POD object.

Comment: BookStoreBook is not a POD, since it inherits a class that contains virtual functions, and has a constructor

Comment: @STIG - You may find this thread helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046244/serializing-a-class-which-contains-a-stdstring

Answer (score 4):

Your problem here is that certain parts of your `BookStoreBook` class contain pointers, even though they are not visible. `std::string` for example has a pointer to the memory location where the contents of the string are kept.

It is virtually always considered a bad practice to write data structures in C++ to disk as they appear in memory. Doing this does not account for different endianness of different machines, word width on different machines (`int` or `long` may differ in size on 32bit and 64bit machines), and you run into all the pointer trouble.

You should push each of the fields of your `BookStoreBook` to the output stream, along the lines of

```
file << book.isbn << ' ';
file << book.title << ' ';
...
```

Note that the above is very bad practice, as the decoding gets horribly difficult.  I suggest you use [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) for this, or write your own methods that can read/write key-value-pairs from a file, or you might want to look into [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) or [tinyxml2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/). This whole topic can get quite convoluted, so sticking with Boost is a good idea, even if just to figure out how to solve the issue yourself (assuming this is a homework assignment).